# Easyui layout with region collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-easyui

I'm developing a frontend application and I'm using Easyui library to manage the page layout.

This is the piece of code that bothers me:

```
<div id="stgis-app" class="stgis stgis-content easyui-layout" data-options="fit:true">
<div data-options="region:'north',border:false" class="filter">
    <label>north region</label>
</div>
<div id="stgis-directions" data-options="region: 'west', border: false, collapsible: false, collapsed: true" style="width: 460px;">
    <label>west region</label>
</div>
<div id="stgis-content" data-options="region:'center', border:false" style="overflow:hidden">
   <label>center region</label>
</div>
```

When the 'west' region is collapsed the 'center' region has margin that i'd like remove, while the 'west' region is expanded the 'center' region has not margin (and it's good for me).

How can I remove this annoying margin ?

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, the 'west' margin is used for expand/collapse action!? If that's so, its unwise to change it - user experience matters. If you are hinting the splitterbar, that's a properly working part of the library ! Why break it?